# React - serious performance problems when changing one list item

Tags: reactjs

I have come across a serious performance problem. I have an application with a list of 2000 quite a big DOM structure list items and when I am changing one item in the list component like this:

```
changeOne:function(){
var permTodos = this.props.todos;
permTodos[Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 0)].todo=((Math.random() * 50) + 1);
this.setState({ todos: permTodos });
},
```

it rerenders all of the list items in the virtual DOM representation, and this is really slow. The same thing is done in Angular1 about 40 times faster. I have tried to implement shouldComponentUpdate for the list items

```
shouldComponentUpdate:function(nextProps, nextState){
return this.props.todo!==nextProps.todo;
},
```

but the this.props.todo is the same as nextProps.todo so nothing is changed. I have recreated a mini-version of my application in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2Lk1hr6v/29/ and I am hoping there are som React experts out there who could help me with this unfortunate situation.

Comment: You probably shouldn't display all of your items at the same time. Show only the ones you need. This is fairly easy to do in React. You could use a library like `react-virtualize` or do it yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same edit here too, as mentioned in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44599513/2876143). 
Also I noticed two more things that I noticed in the fiddle here. In the TodoItem class, you have to say `this.props.done` not `this.done`.

```
render: function() {
    return <li onClick={this.props.done}>{this.props.todo}</li>
}
```

In the TodoList class, you are referring to `this.done` which is not declared. You should probably declare that function?.

```
{
      this.state.todos.map(function(todo) {
        return <TodoItem todo={todo} done={this.done} />
      }.bind(this))
}
```

Also switch to [ES6 arrow functions](http://es6-features.org/#Lexicalthis)! You don't have to bind this at the end of it. Code is much smaller and cleaner!!

```
{
      this.state.todos.map(todo => <TodoItem todo={todo} done={this.done} />)
}
```

Check out the edited fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2Lk1hr6v/33/ 
This should be now much faster than what it was!

PS: Explore other ES6 features [here](http://es6-features.org/)!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add unique key for each item from list:

```
this.state.todos.map(function(todo) {
  return <TodoItem key={todo.id} todo={todo} done={this.done} />
}.bind(this))
```

Key must be associated with item for example it may be its `id`. It must be not its index in list where are all items lies.

Comment: Will it give any performance boost if I am only changing the "todo" property? What I want to know is if it's possible not to render list items where "todo" property isn't changed from before. To know if it is possible to add shouldComponentUpdate to list items in this kind of scenario. To me it seems it isn't possible.