# React JS - shouldComponentUpdate on list items

Tags: reactjs

I cannot find anywhere how to implement this feature that looks so easy to implement.

This feature is mentioned in this dev talk https://youtu.be/-DX3vJiqxm4?t=1741

He mentions that for every object in array he checks upvotes and downvotes to check if list row needs updating, but I just can't implement it.

I have an app in react JS with alot of items, and I am changing only one random item. React of course rerenders the whole list in virtual DOM and diffs the previous and current virtual DOMs of the whole list and it takes long time.

But I would like to avoid rendering the unchanged list items. In my app - if "todo" property hasn't changed, the item doesn't need to be updated.
Here is a demo of my app: https://jsfiddle.net/2Lk1hr6v/29/

```
shouldComponentUpdate:function(nextProps, nextState){
return this.props.todo!==nextProps.todo;
},
```

I am using this method in the list item component, but the this.props.todo is the same as nextProps.todo so no rows are updated when I change a random item of the first five items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you haven't updated the reference of the Todo list array `this.props.todos`.

```
changeOne:function(){
    var permTodos = this.props.todos.concat([]);
    permTodos[Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 0)]= {todo:((Math.random() * 50) + 1)};
    this.setState({ todos: permTodos });
},
```

This is why immutability is important.

If you think this is getting too complex. Use libraries such as `immutableJS` which does that automagically for you.

Edit: Working fiddle link!
https://jsfiddle.net/11z2zzq6/1/

Comment: Sorry, but I made a fiddle with this edit and it still doesn't work. :( https://jsfiddle.net/2Lk1hr6v/30/

Comment: I played around with it. I found out that you cannot get away with changing `.todo` directly. So edited the above answer. Also included a working fiddle.

Comment: I had already given up, couldn't find anywhere an explanation of how it works for lists with shouldComponentUpdate. Kudos to you!

Comment: Just one thing to note for the future. React updates based on checking the references. So make sure whatever changes you do, you change it while changing the references. For simplicity sake you can consider immutablejs

Comment: Why answer [example](https://jsfiddle.net/11z2zzq6/1/) `ChangeOne` event changes `two` values instead `one`? However if remove `.concat([])` it works good and change `one` as supposed. What is wrong?

Comment: It changes only one value. And concat is important, since if you start using `React.PureComponent` in place of `React.Component` for perf benefits. Or if the same thing you are doing here, if you do in redux. You always have to break reference since react decides whether to render or not based on references. In this example it will work without it, but it's just a general practice.

Comment: It changes **two** values. For example It was "22 27 259 348 498" and after press the button values is "22 76 259 25 498". Do I need attach the video?

Comment: I just ran that example again and verified that it's changing only once. Can you retry. Gif would be enough

Comment: I get where the confusion is from. It changes one value from the original values. Let's say if for the first time values are "1, 2, 3, 4, 5". And you hit change once and let's say it changes to "1,7,3,4,5". Next time you hit change it changes to "1,2,9,4,5". Which you are assuming it's changing two numbers (2nd & 3rd positions). But if you look at the code, it is changing one value from the original `this.props.todos` and setting it to `this.state.todos`.

Comment: There [video](https://filebin.ca/3QNDFZjHNWCC/so44599328.webm) where example runned in Firefox and Chromium. It is [webm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebM) format. I see that code change only one value so it is the reason why I am asking about changing two values. It happens each button clicking. Some times it really change only one but generally two values is changed.

Comment: Yes you are right. The reason is that first updated value really new and second changed value is previously changed value currently replaced with original value from original data list from porops where it can not be changed.